# ticker still live in memory

Tags: go, ticker

Why when I initialize ticker and then update it, original ticker still live in memory and if I make for loop it will kill my RAM very soon

```
timeOut := 10
ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(timeOut) * time.Second)
for {
    ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Duration(timeOut) * time.Second)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for {
    ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Duration(timeOut) * time.Second)
}
```

That's going to create ticker instances as fast as possible, and because of the nature of ticker objects they won't be able to clean up ( they're referenced by the implementation of ticket which, due to its async nature, happens in a different goroutine).  Go can do this very quickly, resulting in OOM ( out of memory) error very rapidly.

But this pattern doesn't make any sense.  There's no good reason to create new tickers like this in a `for` loop.  You can create multiple tickers, even very many of them, but you can't create infinite tickers, nor does it make much sense to do so.

Further, notice you're not actually *using* your tickers anywhere.  Consider the example here: https://gobyexample.com/tickers . You'll see how they interact with the ticker to make code run with each tick.  Note the ticker there is created *once*, not in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> [func NewTicker](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker)
>
> func NewTicker(d Duration) *Ticker
>
> NewTicker returns a new Ticker containing a channel that will send the
>   time with a period specified by the duration argument. It adjusts the
>   intervals or drops ticks to make up for slow receivers. The duration d
>   must be greater than zero; if not, NewTicker will panic. Stop the
>   ticker to release associated resources.

---

Follow the instructions: Stop the ticker to release associated resources.